# CSV append with newline

Tags: python, csv

I can't seem to figure out how to append strings from a csv file.  How do I properly
add \n so that my output is:

```
SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE
822,822 E ASH AVE


SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE
822,822 E ASH AVE
1012,1012 BRIAR CREEK RD


SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE
822,822 E ASH AVE
1012,1012 BRIAR CREEK RD
1026,1026 N MADISON ST
```

What I have so far is:

```
    self.u = [] 
    with open(message, 'r') as infile: 
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        for row in reader:
            self.u.append(','.join(map(str, row)))
            self.f = ','.join(self.u)
            print self.f

SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE
SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE,822,822 E ASH AVE
SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE,822,822 E ASH AVE,1012,1012 BRIAR CREEK RD
SNUMBER,FULL_ADDRE,822,822 E ASH AVE,1012,1012 BRIAR CREEK RD,1026,1026 N MADISON ST
```

Comment: Am I missing something obvious here? You are joining `self.u` with `,` commas; replace that with newlines and you are printing the lines newline-separated instead: `'\n'.join(self.u)`.

Comment: I was close!  Thanks Martijin